# Upload static assets to S3 on nuxt build

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, build, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt js application that is deployed using an AWS codepipeline rutine. In the build stage i build a docker image that gets deployed to ECS and runs there. Im trying to upload the static assets and Nuxt builds to S3 and using Nuxt publicPath, im pointing the assets to a Cloudfront instance.

I tried to build the project on a node instance, upload assets to S3 and then build the project in the docker environment and do the ECS deploy. But with this aproach im getting different build files names hashes. So i need to upload to S3 the same files that gets built when building the docker image. I dont know how could i achieve this last part.

Comment: I am not familiar with Nuxt per se, but in case it produces artifacts during the build (it should do if it's static) just copy them over to s3 in the same codebuild stage in which you build your docker image. 

For a better answer, please share your bildspec.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack will automatically append custom hashes to any content imported into your project for cache-busting purposes. You can put your static images in the static folder and source them without importing them into your Vue files, but you'll have to hack together something that rewrites the local URLs to your S3 paths in production. You're better off just putting your static assets on S3 from the get-go and then sourcing their S3 URLs in your code directly.

So instead of:

```html
<template>
   <img :src="MyImage" />
</template>

<script>
import MyImage from '../assets/myImage.jpg'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      MyImg
    }
  }
}
```

Do this:

```html
<template>
   <img src="/static/images/myImage.jpg" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {         // this is untested scratch code
     if (process.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
       document.getElementsByTagName('img')
         .filter(img => img.src.startsWith('/static/images'))
         .forEach(img => img.src = img.src.replace('/static/images', 'https://mybucket.s3.aws.amazon.com/static_images')
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

Or much more easily:

```html
<template>
   <img src="https://mybucket.s3.aws.amazon.com/static_images/myImage.jpg" />
</template>
```